# PHP7 can't find executable even though PHP is working

Tags: centos, php, apache-2.4, centos7, php7

I installed php7.1 using the iuscommunity repo. It works fine and I can run php files via apache normally e.g. `http://example.com/test.php`, however I cannot find the executable, if I run:

```
php -v
-bash: php: command not found
```

If I look at the php constants, the path shows but not the binary. There is no `php` binary in my `/usr/bin`:

```
var_dump(PHP_BINARY);
var_dump(PHP_BINDIR);
// result:
string(0) ""
string(8) "/usr/bin"
```

If I use `find` I get the below results, but none of them are the php binary. If I try to execute them it tells me it's a directory.

```
find / -name php -print

/var/lib/php
/usr/lib64/php
/usr/share/php
```

How can I find my php 7.1 binary? I need it to run php from the CLI.

Comment: are you able to run `/usr/lib64/php -v`? if so just add it to your `path` variable

Comment: No it says it's a directory: `-bash: /usr/lib64/php: Is a directory`

Comment: PHP's CLI is often a separate package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @ceejayoz for pointing out that the CLI can be a seperate package.

I installed `php71u-cli`:

```
yum install php71u-cli
```

Now I can run `php -v` successfully.

Answer (score 0):

1. locate PHP bin directory
2. create link to /usr/bin

In my case my php installed in "/opt/php/bin".
So i just create link "ln -s /opt/php/bin/php /usr/bin/php".
After this i can run php -v